# Clamping lines with line-clamp and nested p tags

Tags: css

I'm trying to use the -webkit-line-clamp attribute (as seen https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/) but it doesn't seem to work with nested tags.

I'm trying to make this sample works :

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="width:200px; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-line-clamp: 5; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; overflow: hidden;">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat.
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My content is generated by quill.js and it's wrapped by multiple p tags. I cannot change that. Do you have any idea of how I can make `-webkit-line-clamp` (or something similar) works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wrap the two paragraphs in another div, your current code will truncate the displayed text.

Here is a working example:

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-box; 
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5; 
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical; 
  width:200px; 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat.
        </p>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is an example using span tags instead of paragraph tags. This approach allows "..." to become visible:

```css
.container {
  display: -webkit-box; 
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5; 
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical; 
  width:200px; 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div>
        <span>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat.
        </span>
        <span>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
          tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
          quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
          consequat.
        </span>
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works well but we are strangely losing the "..." at the end of the paragraph, do you think it's possible to add them back ? The way the number of lines is calculated is also different with newlines, but it's not really important in my case.

Comment: It appears that the "..." is lost if the elements inside of the .container are block-level elements such as <p>, <div>, etc. If you change the <p> tags to an inline element, such as <span>, the "..." reappears. I have updated my answer to include an example using spans instead of the paragraph tags.

Comment: In Safari 14 nothing is visible when using block-level child elements. This works only with inline child elements.